# ActivityUnitTestCase.getInstrumentation returns null in Android Studio

Tags: android, junit

I'm using Android Studio AI-141.1972460 with JUnit 4 and am trying to write a simple JUnit test for an Activity:

```
public class GameActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<GameActivity> {
    public GameActivityTest() {
        super(GameActivity.class);
    }
    @Before 
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent, null, null);
        . . .
```

The code compiles but getInstrumentation is returning null so I'm getting a NullPointerException there.

I tried using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 instead of this approach, but getActivity is likewise returning null in that case, too.

I assume this is somehow related to mocking? I have

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

in my build.gradle file as well as

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
```

Do I need to mock out an Application object or something like that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Into the same issue and the strangest part is that the Instrumentation is a junit class!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was trying to run my test as a "JUnit Test" (per the instructions at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) and not as an "Android Test".

When I set it up as an "Android Instrumentation Test" (the difference being the Test Artifact setting in the Build Variants), this worked okay.

As a "JUnit Test", I was able to work around this and get my Activity object set up using Robolectric.

Comment: So does it mean you selected 'Android Instrumentation Test' from Build variant to run junit test?

Comment: Right, sorry, should have said "Android Instrumentation Test", not "Android Test". Once I did that, the test code ran okay but needed to run in an AVD.